# Returned new inserted row id as long type cause problems when casting to int in SQLIte Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database which tables have primary keys as Integer type.

When I insert a row, I use:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(...);

long newRowId;
newRowId = db.insert(
         FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
         FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE,
         values);
```

Just in the same way that is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

I do not understand one thing, If I have created my tables with Integer columns, why does SQLite return the new row id inserted as long?

I have problems with it, because for example, in my app I insert a new row in a table and then it returns the id of the new row inserted that I need to handle into an integer so casting is not possible and throws an error...

I need as integer because I use this id later to insert into an integer column for another table that acts as a primary (in combination with other columns) and foreign key at the same time.

so how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` function returns a the ID for the inserted record and it's a `long` value. You can't change that.

The INTEGER datatype (of SQLite) is capable of storing a `long` value, so inserting the id you get shouldn't be a problem.
[Datatypes ins SQLite 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

Comment: Ok, but the INTEGER of SQLite, but the INTEGER of the java is not capable to store a long. My table columns are INTEGER, so in case I would want to insert a long (Java data type) into the SQLlite, there will be no problem, as you have said, SQLite is capable to store it into INTEGER. But in my case, I insert a row and it returns a long (id of the inserted row) and now I have my database model which its types are INTEGER (Java data type) so I cannot insert this long into INTEGER. I need tho populate this db model to insert into database later into another table.

Comment: @user1624552 You can change the integer into long in your database model class

Comment: This is a workaround but I would not like to change my database model into long. FInally, I have used intValue() to convert long into integer but I am not satisfied at all...